# How to get name from contacts list

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-contacts

I am able to get user phone numbers from the contacts list, but i also need names with the numbers,

I know if i use custom adapter then i can get name and number both, but i want to use the default contact picker.

This is my code.

```
private fun launchMultiplePhonePicker() {
    val phonebookIntent = Intent("intent.action.INTERACTION_TOPMENU")
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("additional", "phone-multi")
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("maxRecipientCount", 20)
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("FromMMS", true)
    startActivityForResult(phonebookIntent, 110)
}
```

This does work fine, but only returns phone numbers, and not contact names in onActivityResult.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

       val bundle = data?.extras
       val result = bundle?.getString("result")
       val contacts = bundle?.getStringArrayList("result")
}
```

**Edit:**
I found out that `intent.action.INTERACTION_TOPMENU` may not work in all devices, so i used the following approach, its giving me the names with number, but not allowing me to select multiple contacts.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI)
    startActivityForResult(intent, 10101)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of phone numbers and you need to get the display names, you can use [ContactsContract.PhoneLookup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup), something like this:

```
private fun phoneToName(phone: String): String? {
    val uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone))
    var cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, arrayOf(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        return cur.getString(0)
    }
    cur.close()
    return null
}
```

P.S. just note that "intent.action.INTERACTION_TOPMENU" is not an official Android API, and is probably not supported by all devices.

**EDIT:** there's no official way of using the phone-picker for multiple contacts, either you implement your own contact list and let the user choose multiple contacts within your app, or you can allow the user to pick contacts multiple times until they finish.

Comment: I have updated my question, please check, i have changed the approach as `TOP_MENU` is not official, the new approach is giving me names, but not allowing me to select multiple contacts

Answer (score 1):

My simple solution to get contacts, may be it will help you

**Data class to hold extracted values:**

```
data class ContactModel(val phoneNumber: String, val displayName: String)
```

**Get contacts and map to model**

```
        val result = arrayListOf<ContactModel>()
        val cursor.context.contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY + " ASC")

        cursor?.let {
            val nameIndex = it.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val phoneIndex = it.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)

            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                val name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                val phone = cursor.getString(phoneIndex)
                var num = phone
                        .replace(" ", "")
                        .replace("-", "")
                        .replace("(", "")
                        .replace(")", "")

                val contactModel = ContactModel(num, name)

                //Prevents duplicated contacts on some devices
                if (it.position != 0) {
                    if (contactModel != result[result.size - 1]) {
                        result.add(contactModel)
                    }
                } else {
                    result.add(contactModel)
                }

            }
        }
```